# How do I control what layer a marker is on google maps Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am sure this question is answered already but I cannot find it. 
How to I change the marker layer of a marker on google maps v3 Javascript api?

For example in the image below I want the bus icon to appear above all `T` icons.

[image]

My bus icon is made like this:

```
  var image = {
    url: getIconUrl(bus.num),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,30)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(bus.Latitude, bus.Longitude),
    map: $scope.map, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: image
  });
```

My `T` icon is made like this:

```
  var image = {
    url: stopIcon
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop.Latitude, stop.Longitude),
    map: $scope.map,
    icon: image
  });
```

The bus is always made after the `T` because `T` is stored locally where as bus is live data and served on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `zIndex` as per need for your marker

like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop.Latitude, stop.Longitude),
    map: $scope.map,
    icon: image,
    zIndex: 1// as needed
  });
```

Or you can change it using `setZIndex()` method:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(stop.Latitude, stop.Longitude),
        map: $scope.map,
        icon: image
      });

marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control with z-index option.

```
  var image = {
    url: getIconUrl(bus.num),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,30)
  };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(bus.Latitude, bus.Longitude),
    map: $scope.map, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: image,
    zIndex: google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX // <--
  });
```